# Inverting Rows of multiple columns to vertically concatenated columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Here is a Pandas Dataframe that I have:

```
Trial      Time  Condition             Status       Q    Operation
 ATAB  09:57:09  HEAT-1255      Jump_starting      34          New
 ATAB  09:57:09  HEAT-7319     Farenheit_Rise       0          New
 ATAB  09:57:09  HEAT-5005    Surface_Celcius       0          New
 ATAB  09:57:09  HEAT-7891      Pressure_Drop       2     Rob_Qn_1
 ATAB  09:57:09  HEAT-1000   Surface_Pressure       0       On_Now
 ATAB  09:58:18  HEAT-1255      Jump_starting      35          New
 ATAB  09:58:18  HEAT-7319     Farenheit_Rise       0          New
 ATAB  09:58:18  HEAT-5005    Surface_Celcius       0          New
 ATAB  09:58:18  HEAT-7891      Pressure_Drop       2     Rob_Qn_1
 ATAB  09:58:18  HEAT-1000   Surface_Pressure       0       On_Now
 ATAB  09:59:16  HEAT-1255      Jump_starting      35          New
 ATAB  09:59:16  HEAT-7319     Farenheit_Rise       0          New
 ATAB  09:59:16  HEAT-5005    Surface_Celcius       0          New
 ATAB  09:59:16  HEAT-7759      Import_Eraser       8   Runing_now
 ATAB  09:59:16  HEAT-7891      Pressure_Drop       2     Rob_Qn_1
 ATAB  09:59:16  HEAT-1000   Surface_Pressure       1       Alb_77
 ATAC  01:29:44  HEAT-5005    Surface_Celcius       0          New
 ATAC  01:29:44  HEAT-7759      Import_Eraser       8   Runing_now
 ATAC  01:29:44  HEAT-7891      Pressure_Drop       2     Rob_Qn_1
 ATAC  01:29:44  HEAT-1000   Surface_Pressure       1       Alb_77
 ATAD  08:49:30  HEAT-7319     Farenheit_Rise       0          New
 ATAD  08:49:30  HEAT-5005    Surface_Celcius       0          New
 ATAD  08:49:30  HEAT-7759      Import_Eraser       8   Runing_now
 ATAD  08:49:30  HEAT-7891      Pressure_Drop       2     Rob_Qn_1
 ATAD  08:49:30  HEAT-1000   Surface_Pressure       1       Alb_77
```

For a given time, it lists various conditions, their status and an operation being performed. Various status and operations
exist for each time.

I am trying to rotate the Dataframe in such a way that I put the rows of the Status column onto 1 header row. Then, for each time, I need to put
their corresponding operation under each heading. Here is what I am looking for:

```
Trial     Time  Jump_starting   Farenheit_Rise  Surface_Celcius Pressure_Drop   Surface_Pressure    Import_Eraser
ATAB  09:57:09             34                0                0             2                  0              N/A
....
....
....
```

Essentially, I need to invert the `Operation` column, while also keeping the **Trial**, **Time** and **Condition** rows intact.

How can I do this with Pandas in Python 2.7?

EDIT:
To create the Dataframe, copy the dataframe from this post to the clipboard and then use these lines:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Comment: hi, your example output shows just the Status being pivoted, but your description states both Status and Operation need to be pivoted.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. The example is correct. Only `Status` should be pivoted. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking you could use pivot() for this, but it appears you can only specify one column to be used as the index.  So I think using unstack() is the way to go here.  First we need to set the index = Trial, Time and Status

```
df[["Trial","Time","Status","Q"]].set_index(["Trial","Time","Status"]).unstack("Status")
```

gives you

```
                 Q
Status           Farenheit_Rise Import_Eraser Jump_starting Pressure_Drop Surface_Celcius   Surface_Pressure
Trial   Time                        
ATAB    09:57:09 0              NaN            34   etc
        09:58:18 0              NaN            35   ...
        09:59:16 0              8              35   ...
ATAC    01:29:44 NaN            8              NaN  ...
ATAD    08:49:30 0              8              NaN  ...
```

Edit: got some clarification

to include Condition in the index you would simply do this

```
df[["Trial","Time","Condition","Status","Q"]].set_index(
                            ["Trial","Time","Condition","Status"]).unstack("Status")
```

Comment: Bob, my original post was unclear. I have fixed it as per the comment below it - I think that comment was similar to yours. Basically, I only need one column (`Status`) to be pivoted as I have shown in my example. The example is correct and that is what I am after.. Could you also post what you had in mind for that approach for the `pivot()`-based approach?

Comment: Yeah that comment was mine.  I'm still a little confused.  What I have above does pivot the Status column only.  I can use pivot because I think you want Trial and Time and the index.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I was hoping to get the Time, Trial and Condition columns in one row - if that is possible. Your post shows them on 3 rows - can this be shown on 1 row (like I showed in the example)?

Comment: I updated my answer to include Condition.  Regarding your one row question you would need to include Time in the unstack().  You should update your question so it's consistent with these changes

Comment: This is very close. Using this approach, is it possible to put one of the index columns as a regular column in the DataFrame? i.e. after executing the above (your edit), a dataframe with a multi-level index exists and I want the index `Trial` to be a regular column of the dataframe. Can this be done? Something like: `df.insert(0,'Trial',df.index('Trial'))`

Comment: Yes, it can be done.  You could reset the index and then set the index based on what you want

Comment: But, If I `reset_index()`, all the columns except for `Status` are dropped and I get a Series instead of a dataframe.

Comment: You can do it at the end of the statement.  df[["Trial","Time","Condition","Status","Q"]].set_index(["Trial","Time","Condition","Status"]).unstack(["Status"]).reset_index().set_index(["Time","Condition"])

Comment: Thanks. All my questions have been answered here.